# Do facebook app tokens expire?

Tags: facebook, api, oauth, httprequest, facebook-access-token

I'm reading up on [Facebook Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/). I need to generate an app token to inspect an access token I got from a user. This is described [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/login-flow-for-web-no-jssdk/#confirm), but isn't that relevant now.

I can write software which generates an app token through the access_token endpoint every time I need to inspect a user's access token. However, that would take some time, and I'd like to avoid it if possible.
**I would like to know if these app tokens can expire.**

If not, is it a good idea to just store the app token in plaintext in my (server-side) code? That way I can reduce HTTP requests to the API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you change the secret they do not expire

> An App Access Token is signed using your app secret and will not expire; it will be invalidated if you re-key/reset your application secret.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/publishing-with-app-token/

Comment: Thanks! And are there any (security?) issues with hardcoding the app token?

Comment: @CamilStaps Don't hardcode your token in client side code https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security/#appsecret or anything that can be decompiled/sniffed

Comment: Depends on how well you handle your code, as with any confidential item/password you should never store it as plaintext. Treat it as you would a password

Comment: Well, it is different. A password isn't needed in plaintext, but this token is. But I think I know what to do now, thanks.